# Regex Grouping a Simple URL

Tags: regex

How can get this regex to select every group that starts with **:text/**? So it starts with a **:** and ends with a **/** unless it's the last string.

Sample URL

```
/site/:param/anything/:s
```

Regex so far is this:

```
(:.+/)
```

I'm so close but so far.

So it would select the bolded items:
/site/**:param**/anything/**:s**

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
(?<=/:)[^/]+
```

There's no need to check explicitly for the terminating `/` or end of string, since either of them will end the `[^/]+` match.

Answer (score 0):

This would select the first occurence:

```
(:[^\/]+)(\/|$)
```

I don't think there is a way for a regex to match an indefinite number of entries in a given string. You'll have to repeat the above regex for that. Example in Ruby:

```
"/site/:param/anything/:s".match(/(:[^\/]+)(\/|$)/)
```